# ¿Cómo deshabilitar un <option> de un componente <select> en Angular usando [disabled]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Tengo mi siguiente tabla que muestra el listado de la tabla **CONTROL**  y el campo **ESTADO** es una lista despegable que muestra los estados posibles, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se seleccione el estado IN PROGRESS se deshabilite el estado FINISHED y solo se pueda seleccionar el estado ERROR , Y que se vean por colores, por decir si esta seleccionado el estado FINISHED se pinte en color negro, el estado IN PROGRESS se pinte en color azul y el estado ERROR en rojo

agregué al  la propiedad **[disabled]**  y para validarlo lo puse `[value]="true"` y me deshabilita todas las opciones,no te deja seleccionar ningunaa opción, entonces en mi tabla lo probé asi

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="guardar()">Guardar</button>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">ESTADO</th>
                <th scope="col">COMENTARIO</th>
                <th scope="col">HORA INICIO</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let contr of control">
                <td>{{contr.id}}</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="select" (change)="onChangeList($event, contr)">
                        <option value="0">{{contr.cveEstado}}</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" [disabled]="estatus.cveEstado== 'ERR'? 'disabled': null" [ngClass]="{'text-red':estatus.cveEstado== 'ERR', 'text-blue':estatus.cveEstado== 'INP', 'text-orange':estatus.cveEstado== 'PDD',
                                'text-black':estatus.cveEstado== 'FNZ'}">
                            {{estatus.descripcionEstado}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>{{contr.comentario}</td>
                <td>{{contr.horaInicio}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

y lo que hace es no habilitar el estatus ERROR en todos los registros, lo que quiero hacer es como agrego las validaciones, es decir,  si mi clave estado es igual a INP(IN PROGRESS) deshabilita el estatus FINISHED o si mi estatus es ER (ERRROR) deshabilita el estatus IN PROGRESS

intente agregar un if, para la condicion dentro del [disabled] pero lo marca como error,
alguien podria dcirme como agregar esas validaciones?

Comment: Usa un `*ngIf` o dentro del `[value]` usa un [ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

Comment: @René , actualice la pregunta con la modificacion de la propiedad [disabled] con un ternario, pero como pongo que si el estatus es igual a ERR, que solo habilite el estatus  INP por ejemplo, porque asi como lo tengo ahorita solo me deshabilita el estatus ERR

Comment: Déjame desmenuzar un poco más el problema, lo que quieres es: 1.- Seleccionada una opción se desactive otra en el mismo select. 2.- Darle un color a cada opción.

Comment: cuando entras a la pagina, ya por default estan cargados los datos, entre ellos, lo que hay en el campo estatus, al desplegar la lista es cuando deben de mostrarse deshabilitada las demas opciones, dependiendo que estatus hay mostrado cuando ingresas a la pantalla, si el estatus es ERR(ERROR) entonces al desplegar el select que solo me habilite el estatus INP(IN PROGRESS)

Comment: @René, respecto al color, ya actualice la pregunta, agregue la propiedad [ngClass], y funciona que cuando despliegas el select, te muestra ya las opciones en el color que agregaste para cada estatus, pero como se le hace para que el color de la letra se muestre en la tabla, en el <td> se podria decir , y no solo en el <select>?